# Riddle? Or something else?

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme, steganography

> I ask you fellow puzzler to sincerely apprise, and answer me - Yes or No?
>   Is IV same as LV? I hope not. If you perceive the difference, your first is just fine I would know!      
>  
>   I ask you fellow puzzler to dance, dance on that rhythm of the legend Chris Benoit.
>   I'd U, as usual, I would have done that. If you do it, I'll know your second is alright. 
>   Now my friend, if I ask you to check if my Jaggery is sweet, you might say no.
>   It, at sugarcane factory looked yummy. Prove me that your third is alright, ingest it and show. 
>   Well my friend, time for challenging your fourth tool.
>   Faction of the party says, it's bad. Find if it's an orange or a mango and prove them you are cool!       
>   For testing your fifth, when they ask, if the one which was chosen sat?
>   I, on asking, will pinch you, once you shout, everyone will know that!     
>   I proudly conclude with amusement, that your five are just fine.
>   I give you the code 2-16-3-9-16-2-19-1-4-11 to check your sixth with the above line.

**Solve the riddle and describe the wordplay tag!**

Hint

> Here is a [quick hint](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sense)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ask you fellow puzzler to sincerely apprise, and answer me - Yes or No?
Is IV same as LV? I hope not. If you perceive the difference, your first is just fine I would know!

> Sight - You must be able to see to tell the difference between IV and LV.  Also -- to read that paragraph
>  [wordplay](/questions/tagged/wordplay) Reasoning:
>   - **No? Is IV** - Backwards, reads *Vision*

I ask you fellow puzzler to dance, dance on that rhythm of the legend Chris Benoit.
I'd U, as usual, I would have done that. If you do it, I'll know your second is alright.

> Sound - You must be able to hear, to understand the difference between 'U' and 'You' without it being explained.  Also, one generally dances to music, or a rhythm.
>  [wordplay](/questions/tagged/wordplay) Reasoning:
>   - Be**noit.  I'd U, a**s - backwards spells *Audition*, the ability to hear.

Now my friend, if I ask you to check if my Jaggery is sweet, you might say no.
It, at sugarcane factory looked yummy. Prove me that your third is alright, ingest it and show.

> Taste - One requires a sense of taste to know if something is sweet or 'yummy'
>  [wordplay](/questions/tagged/wordplay) Reasoning:
>   - **no. It at sug**arcane.  Backwards, this read, *Gustation*, the ability to detect taste.

Well my friend, time for challenging your fourth tool.
Faction of the party says, it's bad. Find if it's an orange or a mango and prove them you are cool!

> Smell - A more challenging one.  To determine if a food is bad, a sense of smell is often used.  (E.G. Milk, if not curdled).  You can also use your sense of smell to determine if a fruit is an orange or mango, before peeling it.
>  [wordplay](/questions/tagged/wordplay) Reasoning:
>   - to**ol Faction** of - spells *Olfaction*, the ability to smell.
>  Incidentally:
>   - orange **or a ma**ngo - Sounds like Aroma

For testing your fifth, when they ask, if the one which was chosen sat?
I, on asking, will pinch you, once you shout, everyone will know that!

> Touch - You must have a sense of touch to feel when someone pinches you.
>  [wordplay](/questions/tagged/wordplay) Reasoning:
>   - cho**sen sat?  I, on** - *Sensation*, the ability to touch (More specifically, somatosensation)

I proudly conclude with amusement, that your five are just fine.
I give you the code 2-16-3-9-16-2-19-1-4-11 to check your sixth with the above line.

> *Perception* - The letters refer to `perception` taking the letter of the respective number in the line.  (Nice job, [manshu](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47735/riddle-or-something-else/47737#comment145065_47737))

Comment: last line says 'perception'..taking the letter of the respective number in the line...not counting the spaces

Comment: That fits with the 6th being my idea of something mental - just couldn't find a related tag.

Comment: Nice work!! I hope you know what six things you have found. Now go for the last question - Finding the missing tag. :) Its not "pattern" though.

Comment: Could be "intuition"

Comment: @Khale_Kitha Not the answer. There are various word plays involved. [Have a look at this one](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/41846/riddled-and-dismembered) to get the idea.