# The Basalisk and the Boy of Fire

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme, lateral-thinking, story

As promised in my [last riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72215/thats-a-story-for-another-time?noredirect=1&lq=1), the story continues. For those who haven't read the riddle preceding this one, I heavily recommend you do.

---

> The door swung open, slamming the wall; our heroes burst through, great news for all.
>
> They found the first letter, gaining fortune and fame; the boy is quite grateful, for he'll learn his name.
>
> Their journey must continue, down the road they must go; the King on their heels, of their quest, he knows.
>
> The first mission revealed, his name was broke down; the edges of the known world, his name was spread out.
>
> The room full of rain, had proven quite tough; but next is a sea, of fire quite rough.
>
> The child could go, though the dangers were high; the weather has shown, no rain within sight.
>
> The sea was quite hot, full of creatures aware; the boy's power was useful, when used with care.
>
> The waves were raging, almost ninety feet tall; and their ship wasn't built well, not well at all.
>
> The island of Nobu, the next stop on this quest; a great monster awaits us, we must pass his test.
>
> They enter the chamber, of fire and gold; the monster they fear, is withered and old.
>
> Tell us great King, tell us his name; the King let out a hiss, I'll devour your brains.
>
> He circled our heroes, wrapping them tight; answer this riddle, or die here tonight.
>
> The answer you seek; is hard to find, no hints will be given, from my all seeing eye.
>
> The child pondered, he wondered, he thought; his fire raging, the King grew quite hot.
>
> The boy shouted out, release your grip! I have an answer, it might end our trip.
>
> Our heroes were speechless, the King let them go; he'd answered correctly, two letters now known.
>
> Their journey continues, but they must rest for the night; and as with the last one, will continue another time.

---

### **Notes and Hints**

The correct answer will have the second letter to the child's name, and explains how they found it. Be careful not to overthink this, the first story contained only a single ***true*** hint to the answer; the second story will reveal two ***true*** hints.

**Bonus Question**: Can you find the reference to the first letter of the child's name here? Good luck!

**Hint**:

> Solve the riddle, before the hero dies; if you work hard enough, you’ll deserve pie.

### **The Entire Story**

---

I will update this section each time a new part to the story has been posted so that you can access each part quickly.

- [That's a story for another time.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72215/thats-a-story-for-another-time?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [The Basilisk and the Boy of Fire.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72293/the-basalisk-and-the-boy-of-fire)
- [The Boy of Fire: Into the Stronghold.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72390/the-boy-of-fire-into-the-stronghold)
- [The Boy of Fire: The Final Battle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72468/the-boy-of-fire-the-final-battle)

Comment: H? The top part is a bowl, like the sea

Comment: Not an H either :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Could it be

> O

Explanation

> "He circled our heroes, wrapping them tight" : He is tracing the letter O with his body.

Also,

> "no hints will be given, from my all seeing eye": his eye is also round and in the shape of an O.

Hint:

> "Deserve a pie." (Pi) is the ratio of a circle's (also round like an O) circumference to it's diameter.

Comment: Very good find! Feel free to give the next part a try, though I must warn you; they're going to get harder as you progress through the story. Part 3 will be available this afternoon.

Answer (score 3):

Is it-

> I, all seeing eye could be hint pointing at the letter I, also the name Basalisk in the title is originally spelled Basilisk, so the changed letter could be the second hint that the note talks about.

Comment: Good deduction but it is not, you found one of the hints, the other is nearby but is quite subtle.

Comment: Here... let me make 24 more tries lol :)