# The Boy of Fire: The Final Battle

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme, lateral-thinking, story

Welcome to the final part to the Boy of Fire. If you haven't read the previous parts you should do so prior to beginning this one. I've decided to take a different approach with this one as I've noticed that I'm better at truly fleshing out a story than I am writing the entire thing as a riddle. It gives me better freedom to truly narrow things down slowly.

---

### **The Entire Story**

---

I will update this section each time a new part to the story has been posted so that you can access each part quickly.

- [That's a story for another time.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72215/thats-a-story-for-another-time?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [The Basilisk and the Boy of Fire.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72293/the-basalisk-and-the-boy-of-fire)
- [The Boy of Fire: Into the Stronghold.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72390/the-boy-of-fire-into-the-stronghold)
- [The Boy of Fire: The Final Battle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72468/the-boy-of-fire-the-final-battle)

---

### **Recap**

The last time we saw our heroes they had a terrifying encounter with Loki who gave them the third letter to the Boy of Fire's name. Today's puzzle will wrap things up and in order for an answer to be accepted, you'll have to answer the following questions (all of which can be found here, aside from the boy's full name which relies on the previous three parts):

---

- What is the Boy of Fire's name?
- Why did the King of Men take the boy's name away?
- What is the relationship between the King of Men and the Boy of Fire?
- What is the eldest hero's name?
- What is the middle hero's name?
- What are their relationships to the Boy of Fire?

---

### **The Puzzle**

As the night grew darker, the fire grew colder; our heroes lay shivering on the ground. The child looked to the eldest of the group and asked; *are we going to die tomorrow?* The eldest was a noble man and had never lied to anyone, he responded; *sure, it's possible. But if you stay calm, and remember your training, everything will be fine.* The child was worried because they had received news from a wanderer that the King of Men was catching up to them and that he and his army were half a day's journey behind them.

See, the King of Men is notorious for his war paths. Everywhere he and his army go, death and destruction remain in their wake. He's never lost a battle before, and this fact alone scared the child the most. Would he be strong enough to take down the King?

The middle hero spoke; *Get some rest child, you'll need your strength in the morning.*

The child responded; *How can I rest when I know what is coming? There is a chance we might die tomorrow.*

*There's a chance we might not*, stated the eldest; with Luck on your left, and Time on your right; there's nothing we can't handle.

*I agree, plus ma would kill us if we let you die*; said the middle hero. *Now get some rest, for tomorrow will be the longest day of your life*.

The sun broke the horizon and the birds began singing their morning songs. As the child woke, he realized that his fellow heroes were no where to be found. In a panic, he put on his clothes, grabbed his sword, and traveled to the cliff face to see an army beneath him.

*GET DOWN!* shouted the eldest, *you're going to blow our cover; the point of an ambush is to hide until the right moment.*

The child moved to their position and took defense of the rear between the two. They waited as the King's army began to march past, looking for the King within the horde. They wanted to have the King as close as possible before they began their attack. This was a smart tactic as taking the army from the front or rear would be a bad idea; the King could just retreat to the opposite side and let the army handle the messy work.

*Attack on my command*, stated the eldest; the King was approaching and the timing had to be perfect.

### ***NOW!***

Our heroes burst from their cover and the army began to scramble to protect the King; the eldest knocked the King from his horse, and was quickly forced to back off as the horse charged his direction in fright. The army was beginning to circle our heroes as the middle used his sword and his mighty roar to defend the western flank.

*GO FOR THE KING CHILD!* he shouted. *I'll hold them off!*

The child began rushing towards the King's position to the north; fighting his way through countless foes. He began to utilize his power of fire to ignite his sword and carve through his enemies, setting the fields ablaze.

The eldest, whom was guarding the eastern flank let out a terrifying shriek of pain. He had been overtaken by the enemy and was left to bleed out. Outraged, the child shifted his path to the east and headed towards his position.

*I'm here, I'm here!* he said. *You can't die, you just can't!*

The eldest grabbed the child by his shirt and pulled him closer; *tell my ma I'm sorry, and don't let my brother do anything stupid.*

*I won't, family can't let family make ignorant decisions.* said the child. *I will avenge your death, and ensure your brother makes it home safely.*

The child stood tall; an ominous expression had grown on his face. Like lightning, he bolted towards the King and struck him through his center with a swift and mighty blow. The movement was so fast, that it presented the sound of thunder.

The King, stricken by this movement dropped to his knees. *How? How were you able to beat me?* he said.

*Your army has done enough damage.* the child stated.

### **NOW TELL ME! WHAT IS MY NAME!**

The King paused for a moment, then took a deep breath; I'll tell you your name, but I won't make it easy. Since I'm dying anyways, it doesn't matter anymore. I'll even tell you why I sealed it away child.

> For the letter you seek, you must look to the past; you've already found it, but forgot to ask.
>
> As with all new children, your mom gave your name; but once I had heard it, I took it away.
>
> There can only be one, u and i are the same; but only one blessed, with fortune and fame.
>
> How long will you search, for the answer you need; you'll die of old age, before you become me.
>
> Every day contains what you seek; at night you can find it, in what you see.
>
> Remember your lessons, your challenges won; the true challenge awaits, it's only just begun.

The King then collapsed to the ground. His army knelt before the child and pounded their chests. As for the end to this story, you tell the rest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My current thinking for the answers:

Boy's Name:

> From previous riddles: We have letters TOD for part of the name.  Right now my thinking is that the final letter is 'D' again because of the line, *For the letter you seek, you must look to the past; you've already found it, but forgot to ask.* This line has lead me to believe that the final letter is a repeat and that they forgot to ask how many times it was used. I think it is D that is repeated instead of the T or O because 1. Todd is a name that I know of and 2. the hint that *Every day contains what you seek; at night you can find it, in what you seek* since d is in day and you see darkness at night.

Why did the King of Men take the name?

> Right now I believe the King of Men has/had the same name The Boy of Fire. *There can only be one, u and i are the same* lead me to believe that they either have the same name or possibly the same abilities. Not sure if that is the only reason he took the name or if there is more yet.

Relation of King of Men to Boy of Fire:

> In the kings final words there is an acrostic spelling out FATHER

What is eldest hero's name?

> *with Luck on your left, and Time on your right; there's nothing we can't handle.*   This line has lead me to believe the heroes may be the embodiment of Luck and Time (or are at least named after them) I would guess the eldest is time. Which would mean ...

What is middle hero's name?

> that the middle hero's name is Luck.

What are their relationship to the Boy of Fire?

*I won't, family can't let family make ignorant decisions. said the child. I will avenge your death, and ensure your brother makes it home safely.*

> This line makes me think the are likely family but since in the previous line the eldest said *tell my ma* not our ma or tell ma that they are not brothers. Right now best guess is cousins.

Comment: Keep up the good work!

Comment: Keep going! I'm enjoying this answer.

Comment: I have a question. What is the significance of using 'u' and 'i' instead of 'you' and 'I'?

Comment: @nikki It was a red herring to help prevent instant linkage to father and son. Instead the first thought would typically be to look for some similarity between the letters for example, possibly coming up with Y since it looks like I with a U on top. Although with modern texting this probably wasn’t as distracting as it should have been. I will explain it all further in a Making Of answer later this week.

Comment: @PerpetualJ don't worry it was plenty distracting... I couldn't for the life of me figure it out and had tried substituting i's and u's all over the place trying to find something