# A Quick Easy Riley

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge, rhyme, affix-riddle

I've hit a road block with my story riddles and need to refresh my mindset; therefore, I am writing a quick and easy puzzle for the community to solve. Good luck to all of you!

> Look for the prefix, in order of real teal; using this combo, I'll help you feel.
>
> It's the suffix you seek, contained in all light; look at the table, 89 on the right.
>
> Echoed the infix, two in a row; after the rain, you'll see quite a bow.
>
> Study this riddle, and take your time; if you think hard, the answer you'll find.

**Hint**:

> You’re stuck on this riddle, analyze each word; flip it, reverse it, unscramble each term.

**Hint**:

> The prefix you need, tis not in a whale; but can be found, in a tree, on a trail.

Comment: Does the letters at the start of each line have to do with this? Is the third line a rainbow?

Comment: Probably; It's too good to be a coincidence

Comment: I knew it would be neither quick nor easy after I read the first letter of each line.

Comment: The suffix is probably "AC" for the periodic table elements it's on the left so the right would be a lie

Comment: @YoutRied off by one look to the left and then look at the hint closer. (I think I'm specific enough that you know what I mean, but not enough for rot13.)

Comment: Is suffix RA coz 89 on the right in periodic table

Comment: “Contained in all light...” sounds like RA

Comment: Prefix might be HO(hydrogen+oxygen, water)

Comment: Uh oh. When I upvoted your [this other brilliant riddle of yours](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72215/thats-a-story-for-another-time)... I consequently made you be left with $1$,$666$ reputation! Someone, upvote this! I ran out of upvotes! Let not the number of the beast curse @PerpetualJ!

Comment: Clever as always, @PerpetualJ.

Comment: I try quite hard to make these interesting! :) Glad you're enjoying it!

Comment: Is the last line of the original riddle important, or is it just flavor?

Comment: Just flavor, the first three lines are what you want!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Before the answer, big thanks to gabbo1092 for doing the hard work on this puzzle. If you like my answer, go upvote his as well.

The word is

> **Truth**

Explanation

Acrostic

> The poem's acrostic spells out **LIES**, implying that we need to find the opposite or reverse of what the hints point to.

Look for the prefix, in order of real teal; using this combo, I'll help you feel.

> Real Teal start with the letters R and T. Flip them and you get **TR**

Echoed the infix, two in a row; after the rain, you'll see quite a bow.

> This is a lie. the letter only happens once. But it is shapped like a rainbow, just upside down: **U**

It's the suffix you seek, contained in all light; look at the table, 89 on the right.

> Element 89 is on the left (not right) of Element 90, which is Thorium **TH**. The letters TH are found in "all light" with the TH being reversed.

Finally

> **TRUTH** itself is the opposite of **LIES** and thus fits the theme of the puzzle quite well.

Comment: Very good find! I'm just curious, did you figure out the infix before or after the suffix?

Comment: After. I actually was just trying out all the elements around 89, 98, 86, and 68 for a while and finally ended up with rot13(GEGU). From there the infix became clear.

Answer (score 5):

## **Partial Answer**

Spit balling a bit here but here are my thoughts

> As pointed out the acrostic of LIES from the first letter of each line shows us we need to think of things indirectly

Look for the prefix, in order of real teal; using this combo, I'll help you feel.

> maybe tr? it is the prefix in tree and trail. Also maybe referencing a triple combo. Also the hint **r**eal **t**eal initials flipped. Also the hint of not in a whale shows to ignore the letters a, e & l and instead look at the letters in tree and trail.

It's the suffix you seek, contained in all light; look at the table, 89 on the right.

> element Ra, radium with element 89 to its right. this leaves the suffix as Ra or flipped Ar.

Echoed the infix, two in a row; after the rain, you'll see quite a bow.

> For this I thought of the viral double rainbow video.Not sure where to go from here exactly but still looking. Also looking into the *you'll* and *see*, specifically the repetition of the l and the e as they are echoed/two in a row.

Comment: So you've scored the prefix! The suffix is incorrect, but you're on the right track with flipping things. The infix is heading the right direction, but you'll need to break that line down a lot and follow the same applications as the lines above.

Answer (score 3):

Partial Answer /Thoughts for the community

Feel free to steal any of my reasoning for your answer, if I get anything right

Look for the prefix, in order of real teal; using this combo, I'll help you feel.

> 

It's the suffix you seek, contained in all light; look at the table, 89 on the right.

> Periodic table, Actinium is number 89. But this riddle is all about lies and reversal, so maybe we need Californium, which is 98.

Echoed the infix, two in a row; after the rain, you'll see quite a bow.

> Something about a rainbow

Study this riddle, and take your time; if you think hard, the answer you'll find.

> Not sure if this is part of the riddle or just flavor.

Hint:

You’re stuck on this riddle, analyze each word; flip it, reverse it, unscramble each term.

Hint:

The prefix you need, tis not in a whale; but can be found, in a tree, on a trail.

> A branch? Branches on trees, and trails can branch off in many directions.

Also:

> first letter of each line spells LIES.

Comment: You're on the right track by looking at the periodic table; however, everything except the acrostic is incorrect. Keep up the good work! Think more literal!