# A tribe's misfortune - A short poem

Tags: riddle, word, poetry

The first day we arrived, under a strong rain,
That night we ate pilau, relieving the pain.
We asked, soaked and with only land to bribe:
"Will ownership help rebuild our tribe?"
But they refused, taking a helmet in hand,
Filled to the brim, a sign to help us mend.
That's how we survived, in a land of spruce.
**Maybe you can guess, what they gave us to make truce.**

Hint:

> In all but the question, you should seek the light,
>  Because the clues to the answer, are hidden in plain sight!

Comment: This reminds me of a kid's story I read many years ago featuring rot13(gjb gbbgu zvaref yvivat va n yvggyr obl'f zbhgu, trggvat gurve ubzr qrfgeblrq ol n qragvfg naq gura trggvat jnfurq bhg pbzcyrgryl jura ur oehfurq uvf grrgu). I can't quite make this fit everything here though ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first day we arrived, under a strong rain,

> **fir**st

That night we ate pilau, relieving the pain.

> pi**lau, rel**ieving

We asked, soaked and with only land to bribe:

> s**oak**ed

"Will ownership help rebuild our tribe?"

> **Will ow**nership

But they refused, taking a helmet in hand,

> h**elm**et

Filled to the brim, a sign to help us mend.

> b**rim, a s**ign - a name of the [breadfruit tree](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rimas)

That's how we survived, in a land of spruce.

> **spruce**

Maybe you can guess, what they gave us to make truce.

> **flowers** - as an acrostic of the trees and reminds me of  [Riddled and Dismembered](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/41846)

Title: A tribe's misfortune - A short poem

> **A sh**ort

Comment: Stunning! Solving this on Earth Day makes it even better!