# Disorganised and riddled

Tags: riddle, word

*Explain every line, as well as the title.*

I am here, I am alive, rapidly decaying, moving all the time,
I am used by politicians, doctors, or even niche artists,
In fiction, I can be custom, achromic, or even mixed with machines,
I need to be fed, pumpkins, kidney beans, or maybe some meat,
I can sadly be hurt, by pointes, tinea, fire, even myself,
When I die, I am given a tomb, rain pouring down on my rest.

**What am I?**

Comment: Just checking: Are you sure about line 3? It seems to me you have one too many of a particular letter...

Comment: You are entirely correct, will fix!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are:

> an **ORGAN** of the body.

Not only does this kinda satisfy the riddle as a whole...

> i.e. Organs:
>  - are *alive* but experiencing wear and tear constantly,
>  - are used by everybody (quite literally),
>  - can be customised or adapted in numerous ways in science fiction,
>  - require a person to eat food in order to be operational,
>  - can be damaged,
>  - are buried (along with the body) at death...

...but also (and perhaps more crucially here)...

> ...every line contains **the name of an organ hidden among its words**:
>
>  I am here, I am a**live, r**apidly decaying, moving all the time,
>  I am used by politicians, doctors, or even nic**he art**ists,
>  In fiction, I can be cu**stom, ach**romic, or even mixed with machines,
>  I need to be fed, pumpkins, **kidney** beans, or maybe some meat,
>  I can sadly be hurt, by po**intes, tine**a, fire, even myself,
>  When I die, I am given a tom**b, rain** pouring down on my rest.
>
>  In similar fashion, the word **organ** is itself hidden in the title!

Comment: stiv, you're on fire

Comment: @JLee Ha, thanks :) Why is the lunchbreak often the most productive hour of the working day?!

Comment: Congrats! And as you can probably tell, I got heavily inspired by [this other riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/41846/riddled-and-dismembered).

Comment: @Stiv after getting the riddle via its meaning, how did you decide to go on and notice that an organ name is also hidden in each line? Great work!

Comment: @justhalf I actually did it the opposite way round altogether! I noticed that 'pointes, tinea' was an odd combination of words, spotted what it concealed and then - noticing the title - checked the other lines for the same. Then I back-solved the riddle.